# Ionic3 call RESTful api with a param base64 string

Tags: rest, base64, ionic3

i have a base64 string image and i have to call a api with other params

My api is:

```
register(data,userImg) {
let opt: RequestOptions;
opt = new RequestOptions({
})
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get(apiUrl+'register/0/register?email='+data.email+'&password='+data.password+'&name='+data.name+'&userImg='+userImg, opt)
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(data => {
     this.data = data;
     resolve(this.data);
   },(err) => {
     reject(err);
   });
});  
}
```

the userImg is the base64 string image but when i call it, it directly go to err, anyone know how to make it works? thanks~

Comment: same issue for me , i am not able to post api but it is working in postman